# Find the limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to1}\dfrac{x^{1/5}-1}{x^{1/3}-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit of $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x^{1/3}-1}$$

How should I approach it?  I tried to use L'Hopital's Rule but it's just keep giving me 0/0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What do you mean by "keep giving you 0/0"?

After you apply the L'Hopital's Rule, you should get:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x^{1/3}-1}&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\frac d{dx}(x^{1/5}-1)}{\frac d{dx}(x^{1/3}-1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\frac15x^{-4/5}}{\frac13x^{-2/3}}\\
&=\boxed{\dfrac35}
\end{align*}

Comment: I forgot 1/5 and 1/3 upfront while taking derivatives :p

Comment: That would give you the wrong numerical answer, but there would still be no "$0/0$".

Comment: Agreed; @user89632 looks like you forgot that $\frac d{dx}(-1)=0$ as well ...

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** Take $x=t^{15}$. Then use long division, or $$\frac{t^a-1}{t-1}=1+t+t^2+\cdots+t^{a-1}$$

You can also think about derivatives of $x^{1/3},x^{1/5}$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $$\frac{x^{\frac{1}{5}}-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}=\frac{(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^3-1}{(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^5-1}=\frac{((x^{\frac{1}{15}})-1)(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^2+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})+1)}{((x^{\frac{1}{15}})-1)((x^{\frac{1}{15}})^4+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^3+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^2+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})+1)}$$

This is equal to:
$$\frac{(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^2+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})+1}{(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^4+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^3+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})^2+(x^{\frac{1}{15}})+1}$$

Answer (score 4):

L'Hospital's Rule works just fine, and in one step. Remember that you are taking the limit as $x$ approaches $1$.

Answer (score 1):

With L'Hopital's rule:

$\lim_{x\to1}\large \frac{\frac {d}{dx} (x^{1/5}-1)}{\frac {d}{dx} (x^{1/3}-1)}=\lim_{x\to1} \large\frac { \frac 15 x^{-4/5}}{\frac 13 x^{-2/3}}$

Since we are dividing, we subtract the exponents of $x$ and get:

$$ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac 35 x^{(-\frac 45)- (-\frac 23)}=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac 35 x^{-2/15}$$

Now we can substitute $1$ directly for $x$ and get the answer of $\frac 35$

Answer (score 1):

If $u^{15}= x$ then $x^{1/5}=(u^{15})^{1/5}=u^3$, and similarly $x^{1/3}=u^5$.  Therefore
$$
\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x^{1/3}-1} = \frac{u^3-1}{u^5-1}= \frac{(u-1)(u^2+u+1)}{(u-1)(u^4+u^3+u^2+u+1)}.
$$
Do the obvious cancelation.  Then ask: as $x\to1$, then $u\to\text{what}$?  Then finding the limit is easy.

You could also apply L'Hopital's rule to $\dfrac{u^3-1}{u^5-1}$ and the answer emerges quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $y = x^{1 \over 3}$ you have
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x^{1/3}-1} = \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^{3/5}-1}{y-1}$$
Note the right hand side is the definition of ${d \over dy} y^{3/5}|_{y = 1}$, which gives you 
${3 \over 5}(1)^{-{2 \over 5}} = {3 \over 5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Or, and this will lead you to the chain rule,

$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x^{1/3}-1} = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x-1}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{x^{1/3}-1},
$$

provided both the limits on the right exist.  Continue with

$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x-1}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{x^{1/3}-1} = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/5}-1}{x-1}\left[\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x-1}\right]^{-1}.
$$

You can use the definition of derivative here, or do the limits by hand.